# Signer information mismatch exception in jar

Tags: java, exception

My application running in Tomcat 9 (JDK 1.8.261) earlier it was running in Tomcat 7(with JDK 7).I am unable to upload document after deployed into Tomcat 9 +JDK 8 configuration. Getting snap shot error. As I researched, understood meaning is there may be chance same jar name with different signature might be available. I ran below command in Linux and got this result. I tried all possible solutions, but somehow I am unable to remove the error.

If I run application with same setup libraries & Tomcat 7 + JDK 7, it is not giving any error. All works fine with this.

```
grep -rl "org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream" "/usr/local/tomcat9_02"
/usr/local/tomcat9_02/webapps/XXXX/WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.batik.pdf-1.6.0.v201105071520.jar
/usr/local/tomcat9_02/webapps/XXXX/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.3.3.jar
```

1. tried to remove the commons-io jar and then tried removing org.apache.batik.pdf jar also. But no luck.
2. commons-io 2.4 and 2.15.1 jar also used, but no luck
3. upload commons-io 1.3.2 jar into own repo by maven jdk command and used from that repo, but no luck

Error is:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8082-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] 
    in context with path [/XXXX] threw exception
    java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream"'s signer information 
    does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getOutputStream(DiskFileItem.java:529)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.parseRequest(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:145)
```

Comment: After 5/6 doc uploaded application gets slowdown though memory is already set Command line argument: -XX:PermSize=512m and -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m. No error/exception to see the reason in Tomcat 9. Please help what could be reason and solution.  Note: if server restarts then it start working fine in Linux